# how to pass mixed (categorical and numeric) features to Decision Tree Regressor in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

How can I pass Categorical and numeric features to DecisionTreeRegressor in sklearn?

Below code shows how to use `DecisionTreeRegressor` for numeric features:

```py
from sklearn import tree
make_tree = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor()
fit_tree = make_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: DecisionTreeRegressor supports both numerical and categorical variables. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I do not know how fit function can realize a categorical feature from a numeric? is threre any parameter in this function to introduce the categorical features? the tree algorithm need to know which feature is catecorical and which is numeric. when for example the  x_train is [[1,4,2],[2,1,3],[0,2,3]] how the tree algorithm interpret the features?

Comment: If you post your full code and the error you're getting, it will be easier to help.

Comment: No, scikit-learn decision trees cant tell between categorical features and numerical features and it doesnt make much difference. You must one-hot encode the categorical features to convert them to numerical.

Comment: If you need to use categorical as it is, you can try CatBoost or LightGBM which support that (by specifying in params, which feature is categorical), not scikit-learn,.

Answer (score 0):

First, all categorical features should be encoded (represented by numbers) to be interpretable for the regression models. To do so, you can use, [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) followed by [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). In the case of [high-cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)) features, you can use [FeatureHasher](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html).

As an example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

# n_feature: number of unique values in the feature(s)
# input_type should be passed as 'string' to be compatible to pandas DataFrames
feature_hasher = FeatureHasher(n_features=5000, input_type='string')
df['COLUMN_NAME'] = feature_hasher.transform(df['COLUMN_NAME'])
```

Then, you can pass your features to the regressor.